# How to send email from WAMP server

Tags: php, wamp

Can anyone explain with example that how to send email from WAMP server, I am using Windows 7

Comment: From what I remember WAMP uses mercury mail, so i'd suggest googling for a [guide on how to setup mercury mail on WAMP](http://www.satyamtechnologies.net/articles/how-to-configure-mercury-mail-server-on-wamp/)

Answer (score 1):

Well you need an SMTP Server local installed on your PC or use an external SMTP Server.

You can easily sent mails with PHP using [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Otherwise you can use PHPMailer which is a great class.

Take a look [here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp) for an example.